# How to enter both Username and Password?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

In my laptop, previously I had to enter both my Username and password to login. But now it asks only for password. I have checked the options and the option “Users must enter both username and password …………………..” is checked. Still I have to enter only password. I want users to enter both. How to go about it? I am using windows 7 professional 32-bit.

I have been logging in to the laptop with more than 3 accounts out of which 1 is not shown in the list during Login now. So I cant login into it now. Also that account is not visible in net user. I wonder why? But its files are there in C:\Users. There are few more accounts that others use and are similar to this. So I need to get back to that screen.

Comment: not even a single reply after so many days. strange!

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure this via registry or Local Security Policy.

[How to Clear and Don’t Display Last User Name who Logged In On Windows Logon Screen](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-clear-and-dont-display-last-user-name-who-logged-in-on-windows-logon-screen/)